# How to keep the underline effect in this demo stay using CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm a beginner in CSS, and I would like to know how to keep the underline effect (when hovering over links in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bah4D/)) permanent. I can use jQuery or javascript to have a focus on the element, but I would like the underline to stay even after mouse focus has been shifted. Thank you.

```
    <section class="blue-green">
    <nav id="cl-effect-4" class="cl-effect-4">
        <a id="focus-this" href="index.html">+ Create New</a>
        <a href="launch_approved.html">Launch Approved Campaigns</a>
        <a href="pending.html">Pending Approval</a>
        <a href="record.html">Your Campaign Record</a>
    </nav>
    </section>
```

Comment: Present always or just after the first hover?

Comment: That would make for a very non-standard (read: confusing as heck) user experience, and would require scripting.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bah4D/2/

Comment: Hi @Danko, I meant present always. I think Morpheus showed me a way to do it. He changed 'a:hover:after' to 'a:after'. That's what I needed to know.

isherwood, I agree. I only meant to put the underline on the link that has been clicked by the user. Being ignorant in CSS, I didn't know what I need to tweak in order to keep underline permanent. :>

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fire a hover event with JQuery when you hover over your anchor tags that would add a class:

JQuery

```
$("a").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass('focus-this');
  }
);
```

Additional CSS

```
.focus-this{border-bottom:5px solid white;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/bah4D/6/)

Comment: Hi @MathiasaurusRex, your solution is exactly what I wanted. Add class when hovered/clicked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Do your JQuery like this,

```
 $("#focus-this").hover(

 function () {
     $(this).focus(); }, function () {
     $(this).hover(); });
```

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bah4D/5/) for you!

Comment: Well done. +1 Of course, for the result requested in the OP, the code would be 5px solid white, as in: `.focus-this{border-bottom:5px solid white;}` -- I know you know this, TCG, but perhaps the OP doesn't, so I make it clear.

Comment: This result isn't permanent. When you click anywhere on the page the underline is removed.

Comment: Hi @TheCodeGuru, thank you for the help. But just like MathiasaurusRex pointed out, I would like the underline to be permanent no matter where I click. The goal is to keep the underline on the link that was most recently clicked. If you have time, could you please update the fiddle to show me the right approach? Thank you.

Comment: @gibberish Thanks. 
user1330974 Sorry I was a bit late to update it. Seems you got the answer already :)

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex Congrats on your solution.